# materializecss: how can I get an image to stay within the column

Tags: html, css, materialize

I work with the materializecss grid system and I have a s6 col. ( `<div class="col s6 center-align">`)
Now when I put a (large) image in it, I want the image to scale so it will not move out of the column.
The image is this:

```
<img class="responsive-img" src="{{getImageName()}}">
```

Now on a small screen, the image doesn't respect the column boundaries and fills the entire width of the screen (also it goes out of the container)

Comment: Please add your css of `responsive-img`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale an image using `width` and `height`. `width: 100%;` fits the image's width to the width of its parent. And `height: auto;` scales the height of the image automatically depending on its current width.

```
.responsive-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**Edit:** Notice, that if there is padding on your parent element, you have to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the parent element.

Answer (score 2):

please add

```
.responsive-img{ width:100%;}
```